# Read JSON object into vector of vectors

Tags: c++, json, boost

Given `input.json`:

```
{
    "Identifier1": {
        "height": 120,
        "metrics": [
            [
                -3, -2, -1
            ],
            [
                0, 1, 2, 3
            ]
        ]
    },
    "Identifier2": {
        "height": 130,
        "metrics": [
            [
                -3, -2, -1, -4
            ],
            [
                0, 1
            ],
            [
                5, 7
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to read `"Identifier2" -> "metrics"` into a `vector` of `vector` of `int`s in my code.

I tried to follow the suggestion [here](https://github.com/boostorg/json/issues/223#issuecomment-682867163) and tried:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
using namespace boost::json;
#include <vector>
int main() {
    auto const jv = value_from("input.json"); // to read in the entire json file into object jv
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> metrics;
    metrics = value_to(jv);// ? What exactly should go here?
}
```

The code does not compile at present because `metrics = value_to(jv);` is syntactically wrong. How can I specify that I am interested in `Identifier2 -> metrics`'s content?

Comment: IDK, but a quick read of the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html) and I came up with this `auto jv = value_from("input.json");` note the `const` has been removed and then this `metrics = value_to<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(jv.as_object()["Identifier2"].as_object()["metrics"]);`. That at least compiles, whether it works or whether it represents good practice I have no idea.

Comment: TY, This does compile. However, it gives a run time error of an exception thrown in an internal boost function. Let me try to understand the documentation's `as_object` functionality more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment above is basically correct, but another issue is that the code you have to parse the JSON file does nothing of the sort. In fact it doesn't read the file at all, instead it turns the string `"input.json"` into an array

Here's some working code, which parses the input, extracts the data and then prints it out.

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace boost::json;

int main()
{
    // parse the JSON file
    std::ifstream file("input.json");
    std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
    value jv = parse(content);
    // extract Identifier2/metrics as a 2D int vector
    auto metrics = value_to<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(jv
       .as_object()["Identifier2"]
       .as_object()["metrics"]);
    // print the vector
    for (const auto& i : metrics)
    {
        for (int j : i)
            std::cout << j << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output

```
-3 -2 -1 -4
0 1
5 7
```

As before I have no idea if this code represents good practice. This is my first time using this library.

Comment: I approve of this approach, for using `value_to`! I'd simply and avoid `using namespace`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/262fbb14074f5d42. Consider streaming large files instead: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbd742b44ef6da1a (error handling might be improved)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.md) (Small note I am the author). Code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"

class Person
{
    friend class ThorsAnvil::Serialize::Traits<Person>;
    int                           height;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> metrics;
    public:
};

// Declare the traits.
// Specifying what members need to be serialized.
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Person, height, metrics);

int main()
{
    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImporter;
    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExporter;

    std::map<std::string, Person>   data;

    std::cin >> jsonImporter(data);
}
```

Compiled with:

> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -I /opt/homebrew/include/ -L /opt/homebrew/lib/ -lThorSerialize17 -lThorsLogging17